# Webflow2: not pre-populating the form on back button

Tags: spring-webflow-2

I am new to webflow 2 and I have query regarding the pre-population of the form with previous data on clicking the back botton.
I developed a simple application using webflow 2, in which I fill the form and submit and get the results accordingly. But when i click the back button the form doesnt show any of the previously filled data by me? Is it that webflow 2 gets back to its previous state when one clicks the back button and lose all the bound data with the model?

I have used the form tag library from spring in my form.

Could someone help me understand that why is it happening?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you populate your model? Are you using flow-bound beans for that? It is very difficult to figure out what's going on without actual flow definition. Could you edit your question to provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

When using webflow there is a tag named transition.This tag has an attribute history ,it can get these values {preserve,discard,invalidate} witch is described below

Description : Sets the state history policy for this transition. The default is 'preserve', which allows back-tracking to the current state after this transition executes. 'discard' prevents back-tracking to the state, and 'invalidate' prevents back-tracking to the state as well as any previously entered view-state.